# gui tabbed pane - how to put a inner class into my tabbed pane

Tags: java, user-interface

this is a homework and currently stuck on how to put inner class into my tabbed pane.

Currently i have my main page which is the tabbed pane which the user will select accordingly to the pane.

Below is my tabbed pane class and further down is my ticket class.
Currently i have created a inner class called Booking() in my Ticket() class.
The problem now is how do i call and use it in my tabbed pane class

Tickets t1 = new Booking()

tp.addTab("Booking", t1.Booking());

This 2 code i have added in my code but it is giving my errors. So my question is how to use the inner class (Booking()) which is inside of Ticket class and use it in my tabbed pane.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class tabbedThemePark{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("RR THEME PARK");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();

    tp.addTab("Intro",new IntroPanel());
    tp.addTab("Tickets",new Tickets());
    Tickets t1 = new Booking();
    tp.addTab("Booking", t1.Booking());

    frame.add(tp);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

 }
```

This is my ticket class

```
public class Tickets extends JPanel
{
  public Tickets()
  {
      //coding
  }

  public class Booking
  {
     public Booking()
     {
      //coding
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Tickets t1 = new Booking();
```

does not make sense because `Booking` is not a *subclass* of `Tickets`, but an *inner* class. You would first need to create a `Tickets` instance, and then create a new `Booking` instance within it.

Like so

```
Tickets t1 = new Tickets();
tp.addTab("Booking", t1.new Booking());
```

Refer to this for help on [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).